# pouchdb replicate from couchdb : very slow

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I got a ~10k entries(~30Mo, no attachment) database in my couchDB.

Using Pouchdb browser-side, when replicating from couch, it takes really a while to complete...

What surprise me is the amount of requests my couch receives during it (thousands!, I guess as many as documents) — is that normal ?

Is there a way to "bulk" those requests and generally accelerate the replicating process ?

Thank you.

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but explicitly using websql as the local adapter made a big difference to the speed of my applications: new PouchDB('name', { adapter: 'websql' })

Comment: My comment is not strictly related to couchdb. In many applications that potentially need to retrieve a lot of data, it is advisable just to retrieve *headers* of the data instead of the *details* in the beginning. Most users just look at the *headers* without looking at the *details*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you're using the `PouchDB.replicate` function

In that case, try modifying the `batch_size` option:

```
PouchDB.replicate('mydb', 'http://localhost:5984/mydb', {batch_size: large_val})
```

where `large_val` is higher than the default of `100`. The higher the value, the faster the replication should go, but the more memory it will use, so be careful.

See the [API reference](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication)

Edit: Also note the option `batches_limit` which defaults to `10`. This is how many requests may run in parallel at any time, so the number of documents in memory equals `batch_size * batches_limit`.

Comment: Assuming my 10k entries, if I set bacth_size to 10000, will I have only 1 request ?

Comment: @abernier That's the idea. One of the best ways to minimize the time it takes for a database replication like this is to minimize the number of requests, so put it as high as you **safely** can. Every one of those 10000 entries will be loaded into memory at the same time so make the device you are uploading to has enough memory. Note the edit in my answer referring to `batches_limit`.